# Exception in HQL query QuerySyntaxException unexpected token: >=

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I have the following query that works PERFECTLY in MySQL. But when I converted the same query in HQL, it shows exception.

In MySQL:

```
SET @periodDate='1988-07-01';
SET @completionDate='1957-06-30';
SELECT * FROM building_register_period WHERE  active = 1 
AND start_period_date <= @periodDate 
AND (CASE WHEN end_period_date IS NOT NULL THEN end_period_date >= @periodDate ELSE TRUE END)
AND (CASE WHEN constructed_start_date IS NOT NULL THEN constructed_start_date <= @completionDate ELSE TRUE END)
AND (CASE WHEN constructed_end_date IS NOT NULL THEN constructed_end_date >= @completionDate ELSE TRUE END);
```

in hibernate

```
StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder(" from BuildingRegisterPeriodModel brpm where brpm.active=true ");


            if(propertyValue1!=null && !propertyValue1.equals("") && propertyValue2!=null && !propertyValue2.equals("")) {
                hql.append("and brpm.startPeriodDate <= :periodDate and (case when brpm.endPeriodDate is not null then brpm.endPeriodDate >= :periodDate else true end) and (case when brpm.constructedStartDate is not null then brpm.constructedStartDate <= :constructedDate else true end) and (case brpm.constructedEndDate is not null then brpm.constructedEndDate >= :constructedDate else true end) ");
            }
```

Here, periodDate and constructedDate are 2 parameters.

Comment: Please don't down vote the question without any reason.

Answer (score 2):

Case is supported in the where clause, but not in the select clause in HB3. (As per Hibernate documentation)

Comment: Thanks, What is the alternative?

Comment: I am using Hibernate 4.3

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OR` is this case it will work perfect.

```
 hql.append("and brpm.startPeriodDate <= :periodDate and (brpm.endPeriodDate is null or brpm.endPeriodDate >= :periodDate ) and (brpm.constructedStartDate is null or brpm.constructedStartDate <= :constructedDate ) and (brpm.constructedEndDate is null or brpm.constructedEndDate >= :constructedDate ) ");
```

Comment: Thanks a MILLION, that's PERFECT.

Comment: @MehmoodMemon My pleasure :)